# Sverchok The grease pencil is moving but not the polyline visual

Tags: animation, mesh, node-editor, add-on, sverchok

I'm very new to sverchok addon, and I want to use it in a really easy way.
But now I have a big problem: 
I've parented my grease pencil layer to an moving empty, but the polyline visual effect of sverchok doesn't move with the empty. Is there a solution to this ? 
[image: sverchok issue]

Comment: Since this is very add-on specific, have you tried asking the add-on author(s)?

Comment: Yes i've tried but their forum is more for bugs than for basics help so I guess my question won't be answered there

Comment: Please, how to reproduce this result?

Comment: If you use parant, than use matrix from parant object to apply it to GP inside sverchok. It is matrix deal.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/nortikin/c8716923f5d87773b25d417f1610d6dc
this is applying of matrix (4-th node from the left side)
It is simple one node

[image]